# Calling JavaScript via PHP (Reference Error)

Tags: javascript, php

I try to avoid JavaScript as much as I can and don't know much about it but I need to call a JS Functions that shows a div after an error.

I tried to insert it via `< script>function(var1, var2);< /script>` but that gives me an reference error inside the console.

The function works fine via onLoad, onClick and console. I've done some research but for others it either worked or the issue was a variable before the function (which I don't have set).

This is my function.

```
function showhide(showid, hideid){
document.getElementById(showid).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(hideid).remove();}
```

I just send the two parameters and get an reference error back (via echo only).

Comment: Show the full code. We need to know where you echo the script tag and where you call `showhide()`

Comment: show the reference error code. I believe the error might state clearly about the line of the code and reference of the object. Also, reference error can occur if showid and hideid are not valid html element's ids. Check these first.

Comment: The script is probably somewhere in the <head> tag, so when it runs, the elements aren't in DOM yet. Hence we need to see the page. :)

Comment: @Shilly I load the .js file via `<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/js.js" async></script>"` in the head part and execute the JS via `echo "<script>showhide('posting','showposting');</script>";`

Comment: That's the issue. Those html elements don't exist yet when the head of a html document gets executed. Just place the two scripts just before the `</body>` end tag. Hence the onclick and such work, since you can't click before the elements are loaded. Or just place the showhide('posting','showposting'); inside the js.js file and only palce that tag at the bottom.

Comment: @Shilly I removed the function and only echo'd the two commands via script. Works now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with `onload` because `getElementById()` portion of the function **Have to find #showid & #hideid** to be able to execute the statement. May be the section including `#showid` & `#hideid` aren't loaded when you call the function with methods other that `onload`.

`onload` makes sure that whole the document is ready before applying any function to it.